# C programming removing from queue using FIFO (first in first out)

Tags: c, queue

I have been tasked with writing functions that add to a back of a queue and remove from the front.

I have wrote the function to add to the queue:

```
void queue_put(Queue *q, Qitem *new_item)
{

    new_item->next = NULL;

    if (queue_empty(q)){

            q->front = new_item;

    } else {

            q->back->next = new_item;
    }

    q->back = new_item;

}
```

This works fine but I'm struggling to write the function that removes from the front of the queue:

```
Qitem * queue_get(Queue *q)
{
    if (queue_empty(q)) {

            return (Qitem *)0;

    } else {

            Qitem front_item = q->front;
            q->front = q->front->next;
            return front_item;
    } 

}
```

above is my best attempt but it doesn't work and I'm wondering if anyone can help? I realize this is probably a basic issue but I'm quite new to this.

Comment: In this case, you should post a short correct compilable example.

Comment: problem is that its part of a program that contains many files thats it requires to compile and it wouldn't be possible to post it all on here. I thought it might be quite a generic thing to remove something from the front of a queue in C but if not i will continue to research to see if i can find an answer. thanks anyway.

Comment: Your queue-get neglects to null-set the back pointer when the *last* item on the queue is removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this one?

```
Qitem * queue_get(Queue *q)
{
    if (queue_empty(q)) {

            return (Qitem *)0;

    } else {

            Qitem *front_item = q->front;
            Qitem *back_item = q->back;
            q->front = q->front->next;
            if (front_item == back_item) {
               q->back = NULL; // single element
            }
            return front_item;
    } 
}
```